# Differential Equation $y'+y\ln y=xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this differential equation?
Thanks all of you already now.
$$y'+y\ln y=xy$$

Answer (score 4):

Divide both sides by $y$ to get,
$$\frac{y'}{y} + \ln y = x $$
Put $u = \ln y$ $\therefore u' = \frac{y'}{y}$
$$\therefore u'+u=x$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the rest.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'+y\ln y=xy$$
You can also solve with exactness :
$$dy+(y\ln y-xy)dx=0$$
$$\frac {dy}{y}+\ln ydx-xdx=0$$
$$d\ln y+\ln ydx-xdx=0$$
Multiply by $e^x$:
$$e^xd\ln y+\ln yde^x-xe^xdx=0$$
$$d(e^x\ln y)-xe^xdx=0$$
Integrate:
$$e^x(\ln y-x+1)=C$$